# Reference voltage source using classic rectifier diodes

Tags: diodes, rectifier, voltage-reference

I want to make some simple voltage stabilizer using operational amp, but need source of reference voltage. I know that I can buy this component, but shop is far away from me and paying 8e for courier to deliver component with price of 0.00000000...x seems to be overkill. And diodes that I have can be counted by hundreds. 
In theory from school, each diode have a voltage drop on it, should I use them few in series with rezistor or are there some aspects that I do not know about and why this solution is bad or very bad idea ?

Answer (score 2):

A silicon diode has a negative temperature coefficient of about -2mV/°C, so a 10°C change in temperature will result in about a 3% shift in your "reference". The forward voltage is also not all that well specified and is fairly dependent on current (which also means that loading the reference will change the voltage). If none of those things bothers you, have at it. It's been done.

A better idea is to use a three terminal regulator perhaps with a voltage divider and buffer. It will draw a few mA \$I_q\$, but will be much more stable than a series string of diodes.

Low voltage (like less than 5V) Zener diodes are not very good (very soft "knee"), so I would avoid them.

Incidentally, should you have a defunct PC power supply kicking around, they typically have an [LM431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf) shunt voltage reference in them (on the side isolated from the mains), and it's usually not what fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything as a voltage reference, even a resistor, when the current through it is constant enough. The voltage across a resistor is linear with the current, so it does not help you much when you derive the current (using a resistor) from a voltage that varies. The voltage across a diode varies much less (when the current varies) compared to a resistor. Check the curves, in a graph with the voltage on the X and current on Y the line rises sharply at ~ 0.6V. But alas, it is not a vertical line, there is still some variation in voltage due to a variation in the current.

A better reference source has a graph that rises more steeply. A zener diode is better than a normal diode, an LM431 is still better, etc.

You can cheat by using a constant current source for the current through the diode. How do you make one? Well, you use a transistor and a .... constant voltage source! That seems to be a recursive problem, but it turns out that a reasonable constant current source and a reasonable reference together produce a fairly decent voltage source. (They sort-of multiply each others accuracy).

In all this I assumed that you were interested in a voltage source that is stable against variations in its input voltage, not in a voltage source with an a-priori known voltage. That is another story, as is a voltage source that is stable against temperaturev variations and aging.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a battery? If you can use it without taking much current from it it will be stable for months if not years. I'm suggesting this because diodes are a poorer choice (I believe) and, you might have a battery or two lying around.

[Toshiba silver oxide](http://www.toshiba-batteries-eu.com/sites/default/files/imagesfiles/Lithium_Coin.pdf) batteries appear to have a very stable terminal voltage with time and light loads (the lighter the better of course). I don't know what batteries you may have but it's worth looking up the details with the manufacturer. It's also worth looking at the temperature characteristic too - voltages tend to increase with a lowering of temperature and you should find this detail from the supplier.